# Como fazer para colocar uma url no web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma service que chama esse serviço:

```
public async Task<List<Funcionario>> GetFuncionarios()
        {
            string url = $"http://localhost:56137/api/GetFuncionario";
            var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
            var _funcionario = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Funcionario>>(response);

            return _funcionario;
        }
```

Como eu faço para não deixar a **url** chumbada no código, como está?

Dessa forma me dá erro(Tentei fazer conforme o colega JJoão me passou)

```
var webConfig = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null);

            string parametro = "GetCidade/{id}";

            //if (webConfig.AppSettings.Settings.Count > 0)
            //{
                var customSetting = webConfig.AppSettings.Settings["serviceApi"];
                string url = customSetting?.Value;

                var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url + parametro);
                var _cidade = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Cidade>>(response);

                return _cidade;
```

pego isso

> An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an
>   absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.

Comment: Quando concatena o `url + parametro` qual o resultado? Faça um _QuickWatch_ e valide o valor.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que poderia colocar na parte dos `appSettings` do `web.config`:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="myUrl" value="http://localhost:56137/api/GetFuncionario"/>
</appSettings>
```

Depois para obter o valor:

```
var webConfig = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null);

if (webConfig.AppSettings.Settings.Count > 0)
{
    var customSetting = webConfig.AppSettings.Settings["myUrl"];
    string url = customSetting?.Value;

    // tratar URL...
}
```

Seria algo desse género.

Comment: Então, fiz algo parecido e quando eu chamava a url e acrescentava a rota ok, mas quando eu chamava a rota + parâmetro aí não funcionava

Comment: A rota + parâmetro, como assim? Pode colocar o código do que estava a fazer na sua questão?

Comment: Coloquei no post uma edição, inclusive com um exemplo do seu. No web.config é apenas isso: http://localhost:56137/api/

Comment: @pnet você precisa colocar os detalhes antes do autor responder, cara. Eu já avisei antes que isso é muito ruim. Evite as "perguntas camaleão", porque isso prejudica a resposta e fica parecendo que a pessoa que respondeu deu uma resposta errada ou incompleta.

Answer (score -2):

Resolvi assim:

```
public class GetCidadesAsync
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serviceApi"];

        public async Task<List<Cidade>> GetCidades()
        {
            string parametro = $"GetCidade";
            var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url + parametro);
            var _cidade = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Cidade>>(response);           

            return _cidade.ToList();
        }

        public async Task<List<Cidade>> GetCidadeById(int id)
        {
            string parametro = $"GetCidade/{id}";
            var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url + parametro);
            var _cidade = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Cidade>>(response);

            return _cidade;
        }
    }
```